# Body/Html doesn't take height from inside divs

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe with the following code:

```
    <div class="intrinsic-container intrinsic-container-16x9">
     <iframe src="adf.html"></iframe>
    </div>
```

The iframe includes a page with:

```
  <body>
   <div id="map-holder">
    <div id="vmap"></div>
    <div id="directions"></div>
    <!--Use this to display data-->
   </div>
  </body>
```

For the iframe I have the css code:

```
    .intrinsic-container {
      position: relative;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* 16x9 Aspect Ratio */
    .intrinsic-container-16x9 {
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    }

    /* 4x3 Aspect Ratio */
    .intrinsic-container-4x3 {
      padding-bottom: 75%;
    }

    .intrinsic-container iframe {
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}
```

The page has:

```
    #map-holder {
     position: relative;}
    #vmap {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
   #directions {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    color: #666666;
  }
```

The page includes the Jquery Vmap plugin. The problem is, that I have scrollbars on the right. They come from #directions div. If I delete this div, the scrollbars disappear. The additional height from #directions is not rendered to the body and html node... any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not asking why the iframe doesn't adjust itself to its contents?

Comment: I think, because the included page misses the height of the second div, the iframe just takes the page height, which leads to the scrollbars.

Comment: It seems like the problem is you want to get rid of the scrollbars. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Got it. Then you want directions div to take up 100% of the iframe right?

Comment: No, the height of the page html/body is less than the #map-holder div. The #map-holder div includes tho divs: #vmap and  #directions. This leads to iframe scrollbars, because the iframe takes the height if the page...

Comment: The iframe is taking up so much height because of padding-bottom in your .intrinsic-container-16x9 class. if you set it to 47.25% the scroll bar goes away. padding-botttom as a percentage is based on width of the container: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom . I'm still not sure i've answered your question though.

Comment: Thanks, but with 47,25% the scrollbars stays. I got the iframe css-code from a post about making iframes responsive.
The #vmap has 337px, the  #directions 20px, the #map-holder, which includes the both divs, has 357px. BUT the body and html has just 337px! So the iframe needs the scrollbars to display the whole content.
So, why does the body not take the 357px?